# NodeJS static server creation for meteor project

Tags: node.js, meteor, static-content

I have installed meteor library.

I want to run an angular project which has no back-end (of static content).

I want to create a server file using node.js for static content.

Is it possible to to create that and execute ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple example of how to create a static server in Node.js that server static content pages,
the following code is in the myserver.js file:

```
var http = require('http');

var finalhandler = require('finalhandler');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var serve = serveStatic("./");

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var done = finalhandler(req, res);
  serve(req, res, done);
});

server.listen(8000)
```

You need to install through NPM from command line:

```
$ npm install finalhandler serve-static
$ node myserver.js
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with Meteor, but it's an overkill.

1. remove the default `mongo` package (`$ meteor remove mongo`)
2. put all your static files into a folder called `public`

You're done. This way your production build won't require a MongoDB server.

But it's a lot easier to just use the [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) NPM package to setup a static file server with Node.js.